# WCF Configuration Error: There was no endpoint listening at

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-web-api, config

I am trying to use a WCF service (I didn't write) from a WebAPI and am getting the dreaded 'There was no endpoint listening at...' error. The interesting thing is that the service has a test ASPX page that uses it without error. So I copied the client portion of the config and added that to my API.

Client:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IAuthenticationService" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <security mode="Transport" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
        <customBinding>
            <binding name="CustomBinding_ILockboxServiceV1">
                <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" includeTimestamp="true">
                    <secureConversationBootstrap />
                </security>
                <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Default" writeEncoding="utf-8" />
                <httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" />
            </binding>
        </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://devsandbox2.imagebankingsystem.com/LockboxRemote.Web/ws/LockboxServiceV1.svc"
            binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding_ILockboxServiceV1"
            contract="PaymentGateway.ILockboxServiceV1" name="CustomBinding_ILockboxServiceV1" />
        <endpoint address="https://devsandbox2.imagebankingsystem.com/LockboxRemote.Web/ws/AuthenticationService.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IAuthenticationService"
            contract="PaymentGatewayAuthentication.IAuthenticationService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IAuthenticationService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Server:

```
<services>
  <service name="LockboxRemote.Web.ws.LockboxServiceV1" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">

    <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="MexFlatWSDLBehavior" address="" binding="customBinding" contract="LockboxRemote.Web.ws.ILockboxServiceV1" bindingConfiguration="myConfig" bindingNamespace="https://devsandbox2.imagebankingsystem.com/LockboxRemoteGateway/ws/LockboxServiceV1"/>
  </service>


</services>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MexFlatWSDLBehavior">
      <FlatWSDL />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
      <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="Custom">
        <authorizationPolicies>
          <add policyType="LockboxRemote.Web.AuthorizationPolicy, LockboxRemote.Web" />
        </authorizationPolicies>
      </serviceAuthorization>
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
          customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="LockboxRemote.Web.CustomValidator,LockboxRemote.Web" />
      </serviceCredentials>
      <serviceSecurityAudit auditLogLocation="Application" serviceAuthorizationAuditLevel="Failure" messageAuthenticationAuditLevel="Failure" suppressAuditFailure="true" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
      <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="None"/>
      <serviceSecurityAudit auditLogLocation="Application" serviceAuthorizationAuditLevel="Failure" messageAuthenticationAuditLevel="Failure" suppressAuditFailure="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

May or may not be important but my WebAPI is on the same server but in a different virtual directory.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out nothing was wrong with it. The error was caused by the firewall which was preventing the server from talking to itself through the external address. Added a hostsfile entry to get around that.